# SFML library wont be found: fatal error: SFML/Graphics.hpp: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, sfml, fatal-error

I'm trying to install and include SFML into my VS Code and I am a absolute beginner as well.
I looked up several videos on this topic but it wont help.

The code I am trying to run is a sample code from the SFML Website.

This is my task.json:

```json
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: cpp.exe Aktive Datei kompilieren",
            "command":  "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\cpp.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "-O2",
                "-DNDEBUG",
                "-ggdb",
                "-pedantic-errors",
                "-Werror",
                "-Wall",
                "-Weffc++",
                "-Wextra",
                "-Wsign-conversion",
                "-std=c++20",
                "-Wconversion",
                "-IC:\\Users\\amirf\\Documents\\libraries\\SFML-2.5.1\\include\\SFML",
                "-LC:\\Users\\amirf\\Documents\\libraries\\SFML-2.5.1\\lib",
                "-lsfml-window",
                "-lsfml-graphics",
                "-lsfml-system",
                "-lsfml-audio", 
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",


            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Vom Debugger generierte Aufgabe."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

However if I try to include a sfml library, I always get: fatal error: SFML/Graphics.hpp: No such file or directory

I looked up other questions posted in stack overflow about that topic but all helpful answer where to include the paths in the task.json which I asume I already did

Comment: `-I` option is pretty dumb: compiler will take your `include` statement and first search directly for that file, then it will append the included file to each entry in `-I` option. You added `include\SFML` to your include path, so it will try to look for `C:\\Users\\amirf\\Documents\\libraries\\SFML-2.5.1\\include\\SFML\\SFML/Graphics.hpp`. Either `#include "Graphics.hpp"` directly or change your include path to `...\\SFML-2.5.1\\include`

Comment: take off \\SFML  at the end of the include path

Comment: took off  \\SFML at the end of the include path and still the same error.
I added SFML at the end of include path because it wasn't working right away.

Comment: @AmirKhan So the obvious question, where is `Graphics.hpp` on your system?

Comment: **C:\Users\amirf\Documents\libraries\SFML-2.5.1\include\SFML**
here @john

Comment: @AmirKhan Well I think that should be working. I'm not sure but I would replace your double backslashes with single forward slashes. See if that helps. It would also be a good idea to quote the build log you get from VSCode. That should give someone here more clue as to what is going wrong.

Comment: @john unfortunately it did not change at all.

Comment: This is not intended as a criticism, just something to think about. You are trying to learn C++, SFML and VSCode, all simultaneously. As you are finding VSCode is notoriously difficult for beginners to handle (I have no idea why it is so popular). Maybe you should takes things a little more slowly, try and learn one thing at a time. I would start with C++ and use something other than VSCode. Then when you've gained some experience with C++ you can introduce VSCode if you will want to use it. And finally start on SFML.

Comment: @AmirKhan I think we really need to see the build log.

Comment: @john I really appreciate your comment.
I'm doing this for university, where we have to code a 2D game using c++, vscode and sfml.
For the build log, as you see I'm new to this so I dont really know where to find that

Comment: @AmirKhan When you compile your code it produces a log in a certain tab, I think it's called 'Output' but I don't use VSCode very often, so it might be called something else. Take the entire contents of that log, (which should include any compiler error messages) and post it into the question above. Please post as text, not as an image.

Comment: @john Yes you're right. However after running the code, the output tab stays blank and and there only the content in the terminal.

Comment: @AmirKhan OK, so what does the content in the terminal say?

Comment: ***Window.cpp:4:10: fatal error: SFML/Window.hpp: No such file or directory
    4 | #include <SFML/Window.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.**

Answer (score 1):

I have already tried using VS Code for sfml but didn't manage to make it work. I recommend using visual studio 2019 (download link: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/) scroll down a bit and click on 2019 dropdown and download. When installed follow this tutorial: https://youtu.be/VWWSc2nqrEA.